# Flutter Cloud Firestore ODM, how to convert DocumentReference<Model> to DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I have two collections in Firebase:

```
Invoices:
    invoice1 {
        Vendor: (reference) /Vendors/vendor1
    }

Vendors:
    vendor1 {
        Name: "John Doe"
}
```

and if I model them with cloud firestore odm generator as:

```
@Collection<Invoice>('Invoices')
@firestoreSerializable
class Invoice {
  Invoice({
      required this.id,
      required this.vendor,
  });

    @Id()
    String id;
    @JsonKey(name: 'Vendor')
    DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> vendor;
}

final invoicesRef = InvoiceCollectionReference();


@Collection<Vendor>('Vendors')
@firestoreSerializable
class Vendor {
    Vendor({
      required this.id,
      required this.name,
  });

    @Id()
    String id;
    @JsonKey(name: 'Name')
    String name;
}

final vendorsRef = VendorCollectionReference();
```

when I select a vendor from vendorsRef, I obtain a VendorDocumentReference. In order to create a new invoice with this vendor, I need to convert it to DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>. How do I achieve this conversion?

VendorDocumentReference or DocumentReference don't seem to have a way to perform this conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I've solved with converter:

```
class VendorConverter extends JsonConverter<DocumentReference<Vendor>,
    DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>> {
  @override
  DocumentReference<Vendor> fromJson(
      DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> json) {
        return vendorsRef.doc(json.id).reference;
  }

  @override
  DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> toJson(
      DocumentReference<Vendor> object) {
    final path = vendorsRef.doc(object.id).path;
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(path);
  }

  const VendorConverter();
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).